# Cmake linking shared library from project path

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to configure cmake for c++ project and link my library. For some reason, I can't make cmake find my library in ./lib// folder. According to the documentation, the library search path should be /lib/.

I have tried with empty prefix and with "./" and in neither case my library is found.

If I give HINT in find_library(), then it is found, but why isn't it found without the hint?

This is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(UntitledProject VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

message("ARCH: " ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE})
message("PREFIX: " ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
message("LIB: " ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH})

find_library(LIBMYLIB mylibrary)
message("MYLIB: " ${LIBMYLIB})

add_executable(UntitledProject main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Shared library indeed exists:

```
$ file lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmylibrary.so
lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmylibrary.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e34ba5ae24d6a09bfb847a46cd669ea7e101e8a4, stripped
```

This is the cmake configure output:

```
[cmake] The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
[cmake] The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
[cmake] Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7
[cmake] Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 -- works
[cmake] Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] Detecting C compile features
[cmake] Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7
[cmake] Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7 -- works
[cmake] Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] ARCH: x86_64-linux-gnu
[cmake] PREFIX: 
[cmake] LIB: 
[cmake] MYLIB: LIBMYLIB-NOTFOUND
[cmake] Configuring done
[cmake] Generating done
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` using absolute path from command line instead of `./`

Comment: But that would not be portable then?

Comment: Au contraire. Setting it on the command line is what makes it portable, since there is no need to hard code anything in the project. Think about it, for example: you have 10 different dependencies all installed in arbitrary locations. How else would you specify those library locations without hard code in CMakeLists.txt? I couldn't come up with another way. So we use this variable, by setting it on the command line like this: `cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/lib/a;/path/to/lib/b;...;/path/to/lib/n" .....`

Answer (score 0):

> If I give HINT in find_library(), then it is found, but why isn't it found without the hint?

Because, by default `find_library` searches in a system path, which in Linux is usually `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

To fix, you can create a symlink from `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to `/usr/local/lib`:

```
sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmylibrary.so /usr/local/lib/libmylibrary.so
```